# How do I access Empathy after is has been "started hidden"

Tags: unity, 13.10, empathy

When I start Empathy with the `--start-hidden` switch at session startup, it's very hard to access it afterwards. Even if I receive a message, I won't see any windows when I click the icon in the launcher or indicator.

```
/usr/bin/empathy --start-hidden
```

As a related problem, chat windows are sometimes opened on a non existing second screen. I can still see it when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, but I can't move it to my main screen.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following command:

```
empathy -h & disown; sleep 20; killall empathy
```